# can't get network-id using quantum_network in ansible ad-hoc command, while it works in neutron command

Tags: ansible, openstack, openstack-neutron

My environment: Ansible 1.7.1/Ubuntu

I have a private OpenStack network, it works correctly if I use the `neutron` command:

```
$ env | grep OS_
OS_PASSWORD=cai
OS_AUTH_URL=http://demo-controller:35357/v2.0
OS_USERNAME=larry
OS_TENANT_NAME=demo
$ neutron net-list
+--------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------+
| id                                   | name    | subnets                  |
+--------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------+
| 5ecc0fbb-091b-4c6a-b905-c73e66e1ffda | ext-net | 3aa6539d-24d3-4c06-..    |
| 76506b52-1980-470c-b438-094e8b4bb3e7 | demo-1  | 52cd943d-7f25-4a11-..    |
+--------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------+
```

Now I want to get the `network-id` using the [quantum_network](http://docs.ansible.com/quantum_network_module.html) module:

```
$ ansible localhost -m quantum_network -a "state=present login_username=larry login_password=cai login_tenant_name=demo name=demo-1 auth_url=http://demo-controller:35357/v2.0/" -v
```

But that throws an authentication error:

```
... File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystoneclient/utils.py\", line 318, in 
inner\n    return func(*args, **kwargs)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/dist- packages/keystoneclient/session.py\", line 251, in request\n    raise exceptions.from_response(resp, method, url)\nkeystoneclient.apiclient.exceptions.Forbidden: You are not authorized to perform the requested action, admin_required. (HTTP 403)\n",
"parsed": false
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the bug in `quantum_network` module, see [issue #7275](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/7275), it requires admin permission to get tenant id, which is not needed always.

Not sure which ansible release will include this.

I use the commit as patch in my release